# JavaScript form submission validation interfering with other submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have used Google ReCaptcha at the bottom of my sign up form and used JavaScript to validate it so that if the ReCaptcha isn't completed, then the form won't submit and an alert will come on screen.

However, I have 3 other submit buttons that I use as navigation at the top of my page and if you click one of these at any point, the alert message to complete the captcha appears.

My JavaScript looks like this:

**JavaScript**

```
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You Must Complete The CAPTCHA Form!");
  } else {
    alert("Complete!");
  }
});
```

The navigation-like buttons I use:

**Buttons**

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="submit" id="buttons" value="Enter"/>
</form>
```

Submission submit button at the bottom of the form:

**Submit**

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
  <div id="html_element"></div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have tried adding:

```
id="final-submit">
```

to the final button and then changing `.on('submit')` to `.on('#final-submit')`

But then the alert doesn't appear at all.

Am I doing this ID technique wrong or would this simply not work?

Cheers

**Edit**

I don't want to change my `<input type="submit">` into `<a href="#" id="button">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add id's on the forms to differentiate one forms submission from other. Say the `id` of the `form` with `recaptcha` is "`formid`". Then use the following and all should be fine

```
$('#formid').on('submit', function(e) {
  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You Must Complete The CAPTCHA Form!");
  } else {
    alert("Complete!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked a treat. I hadn't thought about naming the entire form, Thanks